# Jquery plugin slider feature not displaying on summary

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Jquery plugin that does calculations. The plugin is working almost perfectly except one feature is not triggering.

In this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/aW9Bb/4/) you will see a yellow box on the right with the heading "Summary". The summary lists different items from events on the right. All of the events on the right, except the one titled "Slider" properly list themselves in the right yellow summary box as you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

If it worked right it would look like this:

[image]

This following code is what is used to display the slider, the `o-4` and the `f-4` is what is used to tell the Jquery plugin to display it in the yellow summary box:

```
<div class="sub-option o-4 o-slider" data-type="slider">
    <div class="well">
        <p><strong>Slider: </strong></p>
        <input class="i-slider" type="number" id="f_4" name="f_4" data-slider="true" value="3" min="0" max="10" step="1" data-cost="2"/><span class="staticPrice"><span class="hypen"> - </span>$2 AUD per unit</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In addition to the html I have pasted above, the inline jquery script needs this added to it to work, you will see f_4 says Slider:

```
"items": {
    "f_1": "Balances",
    "f_2[]": "Card Balances",
    "f_3[]": "Program Fee",
    "f_4[]": "Slider",
    "f_5[]": "Monthly Maintenance",
    "f_6[]": "Total Montly Fees",
    "q_1": "Percentage Rate",
```

Lastly, here is link to a working demo script of the plugin, you will see they have a slider also and it displays properly in the right yellow summary box. 
http://preview.benmartinstudios.com.au/jquery-price-calculator-pro/all-inputs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: solved it, try the fiddle below

[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aW9Bb/8/)

```
// old code was
"f_4[]": "Activation fee",
// change to
"f_4": "Activation fee",
```

This works because this particular variable is a number only, not a list of things like a dropdown like the others.  Thats why the others required a [] after it, because that denotes an array, whereas activation fee is a single integer.

Comment: Actually it did say slider, I just forgot to update the fiddle link. I changed activation fee to slider because I wanted to make it easy to compare it to the demo script for anyone reading this, which uses the word slider. And I actually spent about 3 hours trying to figure it before I posted the question. One thing I did was take the demo script and copy and past the my slider into it and just changed the 3's to 4's and it worked, that is why I am baffled that it won't work in the code I have, which is linking to all their scripts.

Comment: you didn't read closely enough... I didn't just change the word to Slider, i also changed f_4[] to f_4. Thats the actual FIX to your issue, try the FIDDLE.

Comment: i changed Slider back to Activation fee to avoid confusion on what i changed

Comment: Sorry Erik, I did misread that. Thanks for your help!! I see it worked just by removing the [], if you have a second, could you help me understand why the [] work on all but not that one?

Comment: removing [] works because this particular variable is a number only, not a list of things like a dropdown like the others. Thats why the others required a [] after it, because that denotes an array, whereas activation fee is a single integer.

Comment: Hey Erik, if you wanted to get another 100-150 points, I will vote up a bunch of your answers if you can help me figure out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21123567/how-to-modify-php-jquery-ajax-script-to-have-more-than-one-form-field-posst I have a couple of answers but they are not working.