# How to Modify PHP/Jquery/Ajax script to have more than one form field posst

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an php/Ajax/Jquery script that inserts a form field into MySQL and updates the page without refreshing when you hit submit. I would like the script to submit four form fields, instead of just one.

I have already updated the database table `add_delete_record` with 3 additional fields: **balance, account_number** and **monthly**, plus the content field that was already there.

Below is probably overkill of code because I only need to modify a few lines, but I figured this would answer all the questions.

This is the php & html page:

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
<ul id="responds">
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("config.php");

//MySQL query
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT id,content FROM add_delete_record");

//get all records from add_delete_record table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
{
echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">';
echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$row["id"].'">';
echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
echo '</a></div>';
echo $row["content"].'</li>';
}

//close db connection
mysql_close($connecDB);
?>
</ul>
<div class="form_style">
<textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
<button id="FormSubmit">Add record</button>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the php it posts to:

```
<?php
//include db configuration file
include_once("config.php");

//check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0)
{

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH
    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content) VALUES('".$contentToSave."')"))
    {
        //Record is successfully inserted, respond to ajax request
        $my_id = mysql_insert_id(); //Get ID of last inserted record from MySQL
        echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
        echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
        echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
        echo '</a></div>';
        echo $contentToSave.'</li>';
        mysql_close($connecDB);

    }else{
        //output error

        //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error());
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
        exit();
    }

}
elseif(isset($_POST["recordToDelete"]) && strlen($_POST["recordToDelete"])>0 && is_numeric($_POST["recordToDelete"]))
{//do we have a delete request? $_POST["recordToDelete"]

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT removes all characters except digits, plus and minus sign.
    $idToDelete = filter_var($_POST["recordToDelete"],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    //try deleting record using the record ID we received from POST
    if(!mysql_query("DELETE FROM add_delete_record WHERE id=".$idToDelete))
    {
        //If mysql delete record was unsuccessful, output error
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Could not delete record!');
        exit();
    }
    mysql_close($connecDB);

}else{

    //Output error
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error occurred, Could not process request!');
    exit();
}
?>
```

This is the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //##### Add record when Add Record Button is clicked #########
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if($("#contentText").val()==="") //simple validation
        {
            alert("Please enter some text!");
            return false;
        }

        var myData = "content_txt="+ $("#contentText").val(); //post variables

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //post variables
            success:function(response){
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field after successful submission
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
        });
    });

    //##### Delete record when delete Button is clicked #########
    $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedID = this.id.split("-"); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
        var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
        var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //post variables
            success:function(response){
            //on success, hide element user wants to delete.
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is not my script so I thought I should also give a link to credit the author of it:
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/04/ajax-add-delete-sql-records-jquery-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm no php expert, but this should get you through:

First change the form area on the main page:

```
<div class="form_style">
    <textarea name="content_txt" id="contentText" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="text" id="balance" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="acctNum" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="monthly" /><br/>
    <button id="FormSubmit">Add record</button>
</div>
```

then your myData looks like this:

```
var myData = {
    content_txt: $("#contentText").val(),
    balance: $("#balance").val(),
    acctNum: $("#acctNum").val(),
    monthly: $("#monthly").val()
};
```

and later in the ajax response:

```
$("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field after successful submission
$("#balance").val('');
$("#acctNum").val('');
$("#monthly").val('');
```

and finally the PHP:

```
//sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH
$content = filter_var($_POST['content_txt'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$balance = filter_var($_POST['balance'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$account = filter_var($_POST['acctNum'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$monthly = filter_var($_POST['monthly'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);


$qry= "INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content,balance,account,monthly) VALUES('".$content."','".$balance."','".$account."','".$monthly."')";


// Insert sanitize string in record
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content,balance,account,monthly) VALUES('".$content."','".$balance."','".$account."','".$monthly."')"))
{
    //Record is successfully inserted, respond to ajax request
    $my_id = mysql_insert_id(); //Get ID of last inserted record from MySQL
    echo '<li id="item_'.$my_id.'">';
    echo '<div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-'.$my_id.'">';
    echo '<img src="images/icon_del.gif" border="0" />';
    echo '</a></div>';
    echo $content.'</li>';
    mysql_close($connecDB);

}else{
    //output error

    //header('HTTP/1.1 500 '.mysql_error());
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Looks like mysql error, could not insert record!');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I am going to taking care of what I promised. I will delete the previous comment also.

Comment: I noticed you changed the name of variable `$contenttosave` to `$content`, which is fine, I was just curious if the other variables you set `$balance $account $monthly` are also so suppose be in the echo statement? And also at the top of the php file if I was suppose add 3 lines of this code `if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0)` with the 3 form fields which you did not name?

Comment: that would depend on your requirements for both questions.  1st question: yes if you want the delete grid you show to include the new values.  2nd question: yes if you want the 3 new fields to require a value.  If you are okay with them being empty, you dont need to do that validation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var myData = "content_txt="+ $("#contentText").val()+"&other_value"+ $("#foo").val(); //post variables
```

In the php file:

```
$other_value = $_POST['other_value'];

UPDATE:

balance, account_number and monthly

JS:

var myData = "content_txt="+ $("#contentText").val()+"&balance"+ $("#balance").val();
myData = myData + "&account_number="+$('#acnum').val()+"&monthly="+$('#month').val();


PHP:

$content = filter_var($_POST['content_txt'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$balance = filter_var($_POST['balance'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$account = filter_var($_POST['account_num'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
$monthly = filter_var($_POST['monthly'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);


$qry= "INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content,balance,account,monthly) VALUES('".$content."','".$balance."','".$account."','".$monthly."')";

if(mysql_query($qry)){
```

Comment: you need a `&` in there

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake

Comment: thanks, don't I also need to modify the php to something like `INSERT INTO add_delete_record(`content`,`balance`,`account_number`,`monthly`)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myData = {
    content_txt: $("#contentText").val(),
    other_var: $("#anotherField").val()
};
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
    dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    data:myData, //post variables
    success:function(response){
        $("#responds").append(response);
        $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field after successful submission
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
    }
});
```

This is an easier way to send several fields (notice the myData object). In PHP you can retrieve and save your new variable like this:

```
//check $_POST["content_txt"] is not empty
if(isset($_POST["content_txt"]) && strlen($_POST["content_txt"])>0 && !empty($_POST["other_var"])) // !empty() checks that the variable is set and not empty
{

    //sanitize post value, PHP filter FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH
    $contentToSave = filter_var($_POST["content_txt"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $otherVarToSave = filter_var($_POST["other_var"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    // Insert sanitize string in record
    if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO add_delete_record(content, other) VALUES('".$contentToSave."', '".$otherVarToSave."')"))
    {
```

Comment: Don't I also have to update the php files with the form fields and table field data?

Comment: Updated my answer with a PHP example.

Comment: I was just looking it over, and you noted this: `notice the myData object`. I've compared it to what I have and it does not have any difference except the first variable is different. I do however see the extra variable sample you have `other_var: $("#anotherField").val()` Am I missing anything that is different other than that?

Comment: No, in JavaScript the only changes I made were to format myData as an object rather than a string (makes the code more readable) and add the "other_var" sample attribute. jQuery ajax() accepts both strings and objects as data and converts the object to string for sending by itself, but in code and object declaration is much more readable, especially if you have to send many variables at once. And you can add attributes to an object very easily (good if you need to add them in a loop for example): myData.new_attribute = "yet another string to send";